# Input should allow alphabets, special characters but not number values

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a react(javascript) form, In that one field should allow all values (Uppercase letters, Lowercase letters and special characters) but not numbers.

Is there any regex or any other solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it multi-language?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply check that a string DOESN'T contain numbers using regex `\d` which matches all numbers:

```js
!(/\d/.test(string))
```